# how to show dates in polygon in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as df, and I want to draw a polygon from this dataframe. I use the code below, but the x-axis is shown in numbers, rather than actual dates. How to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

```
df:
   date      v1  v2  v3  v4 ...
01/09/2012   12  13  11
01/12/2012   13  15  10
01/20/2012   14  16  20
02/11/2012   10  17  18

# Presumably you are using pkg:lubridate, so this would be courteous
library(lubridate)

day = mdy(df$date)
conts = rowSums(df[,2:3][,])
conty = c(0,conts,0)
contx = c(day[1],day,day[length(day)])
plot(0,0,xlim=range(day),ylim=range(rowSums(df[,2:3])),type='n')
polygon(contx,conty,xlim=range(day),col='red')
```

Comment: I don't think `plot.default` is smart enough to look at the 'xlim' argument in deciding what to put on the x-axis. I think y will need to suppress the default axis and use the `axis`-function. I'm pretty sure that there are several worked examples in SO if you do a search.

Comment: I add these two lines of code, but doesn't work. axis(side=1,at=day,labels=F)
text(x=day,y=qlabel,labels=format(x,'%m/%y'),xpd=T,pos=1,srt=45)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to give `format` the `day`-object as its first argument?

Comment: The problem is solved. Thanks.